# Combination of two sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

There are two positive integer sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$, both strictly increasing and unbounded such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n}$ is non-zero and finite. Under what conditions would a combined sequence $\frac{a_{n+1}b_n-a_nb_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}-a_n}$ be bounded but not convergent?

I generated these sequences by some power iteration ($\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ grow super-exponentially) and I have some numerical evidence that the first limit is finite and non-zero, and that the combined sequence, $\frac{a_{n+1}b_n-a_nb_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}-a_n}$, seems to be bounded but not convergent. The first limit seems to follow from the convergence to the dominant eigenvector. The combined sequence, $\frac{a_{n+1}b_n-a_nb_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}-a_n}$, has fast growing numerator and denominator such that both have the same number of digits (or difference in the number of digits is at most $\pm 1$).

Comment: If $a_n=b_n=n$ for all $n$ then all the conditions are satisfied and the limit is $0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.